# Popover se borra

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap, web

Tengo un problema.
Tengo un botón que al darle click,me abre un popover. pero cuando quito el ratón del botón, el popover se queda en blanco, alguien tiene idea de por qué?

Comment: Java no es Javascript, cual de los dos es?

Comment: @Lixus javascript

Comment: ¿Podrías [agregar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/96008/edit) el código `HTML`, `CSS` y `Javascript`? Te sugiero leer [ask] para que aprendas a realizar mejores preguntas.

Comment: Bienvenido. En [ask] se dan los lineamientos para publicar preguntas en este sitio, por ejemplo, se debe incluir una breve descripción de lo encontrado y si eso no fue útil indicar el motivo por el cual no te fue útil.